# Game field (Android)

Tags: java, android

Could you please help me? How to make game field like in Miner or Sea Battle, or Tic Tac Toe? I tried to do this using buttons, but the result was terrible. Could anybody help me, which approach is better for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a `View` to do custom drawing

```
public class MyView extends View{

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //custom draw here
    }
}
```

add that view to your Activity's layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<com.your.package.MyView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't even think about it.